# php how to do a preg_match() for a word that follows another word

Tags: php, preg-match

As an example I'll use this line:

```
/*! jQuery v1.7.1 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */
```

how would I use preg_match to find and isolate into a `$version` variable the `1.7.1`?

Taking into account that the version number in that string will change dynamically without notice.

so in plain English it would sound like:

`find the term 'jQuery v' and grab the following characters up until a space is found`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an interactive php session for you:

```
php > $haystack = "/*! jQuery v1.7.1 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */";
php > preg_match('/jQuery v([^ ]*)/', $haystack, $matches);
php > print_r($matches);
Array
(
    [0] => jQuery v1.7.1
    [1] => 1.7.1
)
```

As you can see, the first match group contains your version number.

Comment: @s2xi if you want to make sure to only match numbers and dots in the version number, then the following pattern might be better suited: `/jQuery v([\.\d]+)/`

Comment: hmmm, tried both methods but it still returned the same array

Comment: s2xi: The point is that the second regexp is less forgiving. The string "jQuery vFooBar ..." would still match with the result "FooBar". My personal preference is to put as little logic as possible in the regexps (they tend to grow really ugly, really fast) and do sanity checks in PHP or whatever you have. bummzack's regexp is not overly complex though, so there's a good point to it :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = '/*! jQuery v1.7.1 jquery.com | jquery.org/license */';
if(preg_match('/jQuery v(\S+)/', $str, $m)) {
        $ver = $m[1];
}
```

Comment: just for curiosity: is this tested or are you able to write php code error-free out of your head?

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_match('|jQuery v([^\s]+)|', $str, $m);
$version = $m[1];
```